# Display message BEFORE jQuery/AJAX Remote Call

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the jQuery validator to handle the initial validation, and if that passes, I wish to display "Verifying..." in a div tag while the remote call is processing.  Both the id and name of the div tag are "verifying".

Where do I need to stick this code to display *before* launching the remote test?  I want the users to understand that it may take a few seconds and that they need to wait a moment.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.validator.addMethod("noSpecialChars", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Ignored");

$('[name=po_number]').focus();

jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
$("#verifying").text("Msg #1"); // On entry
$("#form1").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
        $("#verifying").text("Verifying...");
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
                ? 'PO must contain only letters, numbers, dashed, underscores or periods and must be between 2 and 15 characters long.'
                : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';
            $("div.productError span").html(message);
            $("div.productError").show();
        } else {
            $("div.productError").hide();
        }
    },

    onkeyup: false,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("div.productError").hide();
        // start nested, remote validate
        var HTMLtable = '';
        var po_number = $('[name=po_number]').val().toUpperCase();  // Force PO to uppercase
        $('[name=po_number]').val(po_number);                               // Load upper PO back to web page

        $.ajax({ type: "GET",
            url: "remote_dup_po_check.asp?company="+company+"&customer="+customer+"&po_number="+po_number,
            async: false,
            success : function(results) {
                if (results != 0) {
                    // The remote call to Avante will generate the entire HTML
                    // table that is returned OR 0 if there are no duplicates
                    HTMLtable = results;
                }
            }
        });
        if (HTMLtable != "") {
            var msg = 'PO <b>' + po_number + '</b> has already been used by your account on the following transactiosn:<br>'
            msg = msg + HTMLtable;
            msg = msg + '<br>';
            msg = msg + 'Do you still wish to use this PO?';

            // We need to set the options to correctly drive the prompting
            var options;
            options = { };
            options['pid'] = '0';   // Needed by the returnTrue which is STORED in payment.asp but
            options['sid'] = '0';   // which is CALLED from jquery.modaldialog.js (damn confusing!)
            options['title'] = 'Duplicate PO!';
            options['width'] = '600';
            $.modaldialog.prompt(msg, options);

            // Turn off the faded background and restore to normal.
            // Appears to be needed due to the sub-level of calling?
            $('#dialog-mask').fadeOut("fast");
            verifyMsg = "Msg2";
        } else {
            alert("Unique PO\n\nSubmit disabled for debugging");
            form.submit();      // PO is unique
        }
        // end nested, remote validate
    },

    rules: {
        po_number: {
            required: true,
            noSpecialChars: true,
            rangelength:[2,15]
        }
    },

    messages: {
        po_number: {
            required: 'Please enter a PO #.',
            noSpecialChars: 'The PO must be made of letters digits, underscores, dashes and/or periods (no spaces).',
            rangelength: 'The PO must be between 2 and 15 characters.'
        }
    },
    debug:true  // this lets it hit Firebug
});
```

});

Thanks

Comment: It may not answer your question, but I find that having a "loading" graphic somewhere lets the user know that something is happening and that it will take time. You could try a loading graphic from [ajaxload.info](http://ajaxload.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to display 'Verifying...' when the ajax call  is made. And ajax call will only be made once the local validation goes through.

This will require you to update the div with 'Verifying...' text ***after*** the jquery form validation is complete. This means that instead of showing the message in invalidHandler, you might want to do that in submitHandler.

So your submitHandler could look like:

```
$("div.productError").hide();
var po_number = $('[name=po_number]').val().toUpperCase();  // Force PO to uppercase
$('[name=po_number]').val(po_number);

$("#verifying").text("Verifying...");

$.ajax({ type: "GET",
        url: "remote_dup_po_check.asp?company="+company+"&customer="+customer+"&po_number="+po_number,
        async: false,
        success : function(results) {
            if (results != 0) {
                // The remote call to Avante will generate the entire HTML
                // table that is returned OR 0 if there are no duplicates
                var HTMLtable = results;
                if (HTMLtable != "") {
                    var msg = .......
                    //Do something with result
                }

            }
        }
});
```

Also, you might just use the asynch call instead of making it a synchronous call that might halt the rest of the script execution.

**UPDATE: display the animation for synchronous call**

If you use jQuery animate, the code is executed till the animation is completed, so here is a workaround that works for me:

```
$("#verifying").text("Verifying...");

$('#verifying').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 500, function() {
        //animation complete, call ajax here
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: "remote_dup_po_check.asp?company="+company+"&customer="+customer+"&po_number="+po_number,
            async: false,
            success : function(results) {
            if (results != 0) {
                // The remote call to Avante will generate the entire HTML
                // table that is returned OR 0 if there are no duplicates
                var HTMLtable = results;
                if (HTMLtable != "") {
                    var msg = .......
                    //Do something with result
                }

                }
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: Not quite.  I want it to display "Verifying..." BEFORE it launch the remote test.  The idea is to give feedback to the user that they need to wait a moment.  However, every place that I put the code to reset the div tag, it never does it until AFTER the remote test has finished.  I have tried putting it BEFORE the ajax call, but it does not change the div until AFTER the ajax call has returned its results.
This is very confusing.

Comment: @user1588106, I meant exactly that, if you want to display 'Verifying' text for remote test, that means your local rules (required. rangeLength etc.) must pass before. Once thee local rules are passed, submitHandler callback is called, where you try to make an ajax request to remote validate. It is here that you want to display the text. So, instead of invalidHandler, you might want to move it to submitHandler. But again, consider converting it to an async call and you might get rid of browser DOM freezing till the call is complete.

Comment: Yes, my initial 3 tests are done first and are working cleanly.

I have moved the "Verifying" message logic to just prior to the ajax code.

If I set async to false, the "Verifying..." message does not appear until after the ajax command has returned (about 5 seconds), but does display the desired info as needed.

If I set async to true, the "Verifying..." message instantly appears as desired, but the ajax code is clearly not running at all, duplication is not tested and it submits the form.

I am missing something, but do not have a clue what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohnatDaytonSuperior, updated the solution, please check if that works for you. I have tested on chrome, must work for IE too.

Comment: Rohit,

I copied/pasted your code.  I had a bunch of trouble at first, but after flushing cashed code, it finally worked!!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something?

Just put it right before you call the `$.ajax(....`

Comment: I tried that first, but it did not work.  Similarly, the line before it ($('[name=po_number]').val(po_number);) does not update the web page until the remote call has finished.